# jquery ajax outputting success status

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using a basic ajax function with on success having

```
success: function(html){
jQuery("#output").html(html);
}
```

the callback is always successful giving me either 0 or -1 at the end of my returned html. What is causing this?

Comment: Impossible to answer with this little information. Please show more code and context

Comment: actually I think I need to use die();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your question is very simple.

The url to which the ajax is called is either returning output 0 or -1 depending on the data sent to that page

Comment: ah Im using wp_ajax in wordpress and that admin-ajax.php seems to return a value like that... I don't think I can fix that... strip the content of 0 or -1?